# material UI default endAdornment styling is not correct

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have an Autocomplete from material UI v5 that has the default endAdornment icon. The icon seems to be have the `top:unset` CSS property. This is causing the styling of the icon to be rendered incorrectly.

Following is the code that renders the Autocomplete

```
<Grid item xs={3}>
  <FormControl style={{ backgroundColor: "#fff !important" }}>
    <Autocomplete
      renderInput={(props) => {
        return (
          <TextField
            {...props}
            label={`${translateFullContent(
              t,
              i18n,
              `ActionSelector.shiftGroup`,
            )}`}
            variant="outlined"
            placeholder="Select a shift group"
            sx={{
              backgroundColor: "#fff",
            }}
          />
        );
      }}
      style={{
        width: "300px",
      }}
      options={shiftGroupList}
      getOptionLabel={(option: ShiftGroupListInterface) => {
        return option.name;
      }}
      onChange={(
        _event: React.SyntheticEvent<Element, Event>,
        newValue: ShiftGroupListInterface | null,
      ) => {
        if (newValue) {
          handleShiftGroupSelection(newValue);
        }
      }}
      value={selectors.shiftGroup}
      isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => {
        if (option.id === value.id) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }}
    />
  </FormControl>
</Grid>;
```

the functionality seems to be working fine. The only problem is the position of the dropdown arrow in the endAdornment which is rendered like

[image]

I tried checking the CSS of the .end-Adornment. This issue is been caused by `top:unset` property in the CSS. If I uncheck this then `top: 50%` is applied and it fixes the issue.

[image]

This is how it looks after removing `top:unset`

[image]